# how app extension can access the containing app images/assets/resource data

Tags: ios8, ios-app-extension

> I implemented the document provider app extension feature with my own
>   ios app.  The problem is the app extension was not able to access the
>   containing app images/assets or the containing apps resource data.
>   Does any one knows how to achieve it?.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The extension has its own target in your Xcode project. In order to access resources in the extension you also need to add them to that target (in the `File Inspector` also check your extension target in the `Target Membership` section). Just be aware that those resources also get copied into the extension bundle, which increases your overall app size.

*Sidenote*: In my extension I didn't add my default image asset catalogue (`Images.xcassets`) to the extension, but was still able to access the containing images. Maybe that's an exception.

Comment: I am following that way only. Yes, the app size is increasing like anything. If i go with shared embedded framework(contains image assets and common code) then it will work right?. It wont increase the app size too.

Comment: Sounds about right. But keep in mind that embedded frameworks are only supported in iOS 8.

Comment: oh no... then what happened to ios7!!!?. Actually i want to support both ios7 and also ios8. Any other idea?

Comment: That's the same problem I have. Since I don't have many resources I stick with duplicating them for now. I guess your extension is not using all the images the app uses. So you can reduce the size by extracting them into another asset catalogue and only add this catalogue to your extension.

Comment: sure right now i am going to duplicating the required assets for action extension as you suggests. Thanks for the suggestion :-). But how can i make the common code path to share between containing app and extension app. Any good way to achieve it?.

Comment: Well, the same way actually. Add the classes you need to the extension target as well. I had the problem that some of my classes I wanted to reuse used code or imported classes I didn't want to or couldn't use in the extension. So I defined an `EXTENSION_BUILD` macro in the extension target and added some `#ifndef`s to exclude some code passages and includes from those classes. Not too pretty, but works. I guess I have to refactor later...

Comment: Great :-) let me following in that way only until find the perfect one. Thanks again!!!!

Answer (score 2):

*UPDATE*
If you are supporting iOS 8 and up, you can create a framework to share among your app and it's extensions, and embed resources, strings, etc. inside of it. Make sure to use the `[UIImage imageNamed:inBundle:compatibleWithTraitCollection:]` and `NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle` methods, passing in the bundle that is your framework.

*PREVIOUS ANSWER*
Given that extensions are (and hopefully always will be) in a sub-folder of the main app at /Plugins/PluginName and have permissions to access files just like the main app, you can do the following (and I do in some of my apps on the store):

```
// image
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"../../image_name.png"]

// data
NSString* path = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"../../file.json"];
NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

This will save you a lot of space, especially if your extension uses a lot of images.